# nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "domain" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

Tags: python, django, nginx, deployment

I've bought a domain name, deployed my django application to DigitalOcean, but this error doesn't let me use application. How can I ignore this error ? Here are my codes:

setting.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['blablabla.com', '64.225.12.157']
```

nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blablabla.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/sammy/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/sammy/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

default nginx:

```
        root /var/www/blablabla.com;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name blablabla.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

Comment: Please add your full Nginx conf and also the full error message.

Comment: @heemayl configuration is just what I've posted, but fully error is:

```nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "blablabla.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Comment: @heemayl added, please help

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues (the second one is mostly a recommendation):

---

**First:**

You've defined the `server_name` directive in two places -- one in the default `http` block and one in a `server` block. Drop the reference in the default `http` block and keep only the one at the `server` block. Also unless you know what you're doing, drop the `location /` directive from `http` block as well, the locations are *usually* put in the `server` block to do URL mappings for that server. Putting that in `http` block does the mapping globally, which causes a headache while tracking the mapping down while debugging.

---

**Second:**

Django talks the WSGI protocol, so (in production) a WSGI server is needed to send request and get response back from Django. Presumably, you're using one given by the reference to the UNIX domain socket:

```
/home/sammy/myproject/myproject.sock
```

So if your WSGI server (e.g. `uWSGI`, `gunicorn`) listens on that socket for incoming requests, and also send the response via that, you need to tell Nginx to use WSGI protocol to send-retrieve data from the socket and also pass relevant WSGI parameters. An example of this would be:

```
upstream foobar {
    server unix:///home/sammy/myproject/myproject.sock;
}

server {
    server_name blablabla.com;
    ...
    ...
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass foobar;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Your current configuration with reverse proxying via `proxy_pass` will work but using WSGI gets you closer to the underlying protocol used by underlying layers hence is recommended.